# Make your own data range in c++

Tags: c++, int, range

I want to have a data variable which will be an integer and its range will be from 
0 - 1.000.000.
For example normal int variables can store numbers from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.
I want the new data type to have less range so it can have LESS SIZE.

If there is a way to do that please let me know?

Comment: do you only need to store them or will you do some arithmetic ?

Comment: An integer type that has less range is far, far easier than one that has less range *and* has less size.  You understand that your 0 to 1 million value would require 63% of the size of the standard integer, and would be much much slower?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't; you can't specify arbitrary ranges for variables like this in C++.

You need 20 bits to store 1,000,000 different values, so using a 32-bit integer is the best you can do without creating a custom data type (even then you'd only be saving 1 byte at 24 bits, since you can't allocate less than 8 bits).

As for *enforcing* the range of values, you could do that with a custom class, but I assume your goal isn't the validation but the size reduction.

Answer (score 2):

So, there's no true good answer to this problem. Here are a few thoughts though:

1. If you're talking about an array of these 20 bit values, then perhaps the answers at this question will be helpful: [Bit packing of array of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397655/bit-packing-of-array-of-integers)
2. On the other hand, perhaps we are talking about an object, that has 3 `int20_t`s in it, and you'd like it to take up less space than it would normally. In that case, we could use a bitfield.

   ```
   struct object {
       int a : 20;
       int b : 20;
       int c : 20;
   } __attribute__((__packed__));

   printf("sizeof object: %d\n", sizeof(struct object));
   ```

   This code will probably print `8`, signifying that it is using 8 bytes of space, not the 12 that you would normally expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have data types to be multiple of 8 bits. This is because, otherwise that data type won't be addressable. Imagine a pointer to a 5 bit data. That won't exist.